# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Both username and credential are required when the URL scheme is "turn" or "turns"

Tags: webrtc, coturn, rtcpeerconnection

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Both username and credential are required when the URL scheme is "turn" or "turns".

I have getting error.

My code and coturn config are.

```js
const iceConfiguration = {
        iceServers: [
            {
                username: 'myuser',
                credentials: 'userpassword',
                urls: [
                    'turn:public_ip_address:3478?transport=tcp',
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);
```

```
listening-port=3478

tls-listening-port=5349

listening-ip= turn:public_ip_address

external-ip= turn:public_ip_address

relay-ip= turn:public_ip_address

fingerprint

lt-cred-mech

user=myuser:userpassword
```

I tried write urls without array[ ]
but same result.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification says](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtciceserver-dictionary) the property is `credential`, not `credentials`.
Did you find the wrong spelling in a particular place?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error was caused by typo "credential"

Can you try again with:

```
const iceConfiguration = {
        iceServers: [
            {
                username: 'myuser',
                credential: 'userpassword',
                urls: 'turn:public_ip_address:3478?transport=tcp'
            }
        ]
    }
    let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);
```

Coturn can be tested by [WebRTC samples Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)

[Here has some detailed TURN server test info](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1526/how-to-test-online-whether-a-stun-turn-server-is-working-properly-or-not)

Hope these info helps.